# Could we use private IP address as directed broadcast address?

Tags: ipv4, ip-address, layer3

We know that private IP addresses ranges of class A, class B, class C are 10.0.0.0-10.0.0.255, 172.16.0.0-172.16.255.255, 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255 respectively.

My first questions is that first and last IP address of any class could be used as private net-id, DBA(directed broadcast address) respectively of that entire class? For example 10.0.0.0,10.0.0.255 could we assign for any device? Or are they reserved?

If we use 10.0.0.2 as S. I. P and 10.0.0.13 as D. I. P then it's the unicast packet within the network.
My second question is if we use D. I. P as 10.255.255.255 then it will work?

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years _before_ the commercial Internet) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). We have not had network classes in this century. Also, directed broadcast is disabled on routers by default.

Comment: @RonMaupin if 2 router sharing same ip address then packet will go which router if the destination is that ip address?

Comment: Two hosts on the same network (routers are hosts, too) will cause duplicate address problems. That is an error that needs to be corrected. We have things like FHRPs (HSRP, VRRP, etc.) to allow you to use a single router address for multiple routers, but each router actually has it own, separate address, sharing a virtual address, and the FHRP picks the active router.

Comment: @RonMaupin if both router are active then which one will be chosen?

Comment: The FHRP picks the active router. It is based on things like the priority assigned when configuring the FHRP on the routers. There will be a rule for breaking a tie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending a packet to the network broadcast address on the same network is not a directed broadcast as it does not involve a router to direct the broadcast. It is simply a network broadcast. If your network is `10.0.0.0/8`, then sending to `10.255.255.255` from any address in that network is a simple network broadcast.

If your network is `10.0.0.0/24`, then sending to `10.255.255.255` is a unicast packet to a different network sent to your router that will attempt to forward it toward the destination network. Unless the destination router is configured to forward directed broadcasts (disabled by default), the destination router will drop it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133031/discussion-on-answer-by-ron-maupin-could-we-use-private-ip-address-as-directed-b).

Comment: if one router has IP address 10.0.0.1/24 which connected to two another routers of different networks 10.255.3.1/16 and 10.2.3.1/8. Then if 10.0.0.1/24 use destination address as 10.255.255.255 then it unicasts to both 10.255.3.1/16 and 10.2.3.1/8?

Comment: No, those are overlapping networks that conflict. routers cannot have overlapping networks. If a router has no path, even a default route, toward a destination, it drops the packet as undeliverable. Remember that ever IPv4 network is a subnet of `0.0.0.0/0`. Also, understand that broadcasting is going away in favor of multicasting. Even IPv6 has eliminated broadcast.

Comment: If the networks overlap, they will conflict. Routers route packets between networks, not from a network back to the same network, so router interfaces must be in different, non-overlapping networks. Routing is deterministic, and routers cannot guess where to send a pascket. If a routing table has two paths toward a destination, it uses the longest match and other methods to break a tie.

Comment: once again your legendary answer and valuable comments. I am very lucky to have teacher like you.

Comment: ""Sending a packet to the network broadcast address on the same network is not a directed broadcast as it does not involve a router to direct the broadcast. ""----you mean network broadcast address 255.255.255.255 which doesn't involve router? Am I correct?

Comment: No, `255.255.255.255` is the Limited Broadcast address. I mean the network broadcast address, which is the last (all-ones) network address, e.g. `10.0.0.255` for `10.0.0.0/24`.

Comment: 255.255.255.255 involves a router? Involved router you mean it doesn't cross the router?

Comment: No. neither type of broadcast (limited or network) crosses a router. Only a directed broadcast does, but it is a unicast when it crosses a router. Any broadcast received by a router is assumed to be for the router itself, and it is not forwarded.

Comment: if I my network is 10.0.0.0/8 then to broadcast in my network, 10.255.255.255 could be routed from an outside source ?

Comment: Not by default. You would need to configure your router to allow directed broadcasts, but that would be foolish because that is a huge security risk. Originally, directed broadcasts were required to be forwarded on routers, but because of the security problem, _[RFC 2644. Changing the Default for Directed Broadcasts in Routers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2644/)_ changed that, and it is now disabled by default, although it can be enabled on enterprise-grade routers.

Comment: if I use  10.0.0.2 IP address from 10.0.0.0/24 network, then if I use destination address as 10.0.0.255 then what will happen? 10.0.0.2 broadcasts to 254 members of that subnet?

Comment: Yes, that is sending to the network broadcast address (the all-ones network address). It is disruptive because it interrupts _every_ host on the network, including things like printers and routers that are not interested, and it is now considered deprecated in favor of multicast. Also, it will not be able to port to IPv6 because IPv6 does not have broadcast.

Comment: if I use 255.255.255.255 then it will work as same thing as 10.0.0.255 did? So what's the difference between 10.0.0.255 and 255.255.255.255 , as both sends 254 hosts on sae network?

Comment: Yes, they do the same thing. The real difference is that the Limited Broadcast address can be used on any network without needing to know the network and mask. The limited broadcast was introduced at a time when the router requirement was to forward directed broadcasts, and it was purposely not forwardable. Applications could be hardcoded to use the Limited Broadcast, and it would work on any network where the application is run without finding the network and mask where the application is run. With the demise of directed broadcasting, they basically do the same thing.

Comment: """Any broadcast received by a router is assumed to be for the router itself, and it is not forwarded""--- you mean suppose I have one router with two subnets 10.0.0.0/25 and 10.0.0.128/25 of the network 10.0.0.0/24.Then if 10.0.0.128/25 wants to broadcast on 10.0.0.0/25 it will use 10.0.0.127 as destination address which goes through **same router** and it also known as direct broadcast? Am I correct?

Comment: When the router receives a packet destined to `10.0.0.127` on the `10.0.0.128/25` network interface, it is a unicast packet destined to the `10.0.0.0/25` network. If the router has not had its configuration to allow directed broadcast, the `10.0.0.0/25` interface of the router will see it as a directed broadcast and drop it. If the router has been configured to allow directed broadcast, the the `10.0.0.0/25` interface will see it as a broadcast and encapsulate it in a layer-2 broadcast frame.

Comment: in this case what would be the router's IP address? I mean if my device is connected to router then device and router uses different public IP address? Or device could be use private IP address and router uses public IP address  and uses NAT?

Comment: The router address can be any valid network host address. There is nothing special about a router address. The rest of the question depends on how you have configured the router.

Comment: one thing tell "any device to connect the internet they uses the router"--it  means device and  router has same IP address?

Comment: Not necessarily, for example, dial up did not use a router, and you can certainly connect a PC directly to a DSL or cable modem. Routers route packets between networks, so to get traffic from one network to another requires a router between each network in the path between the source and destination if they are on different networks.

Comment: if router has 2 different subnet then router has two different IP address?

Comment: Yes. Each router interface has an address in the network to which the interface is connected.

Comment: our home router could be default gateway?

Comment: Home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: I mean LAN connected to router could be said default gateway?

Comment: A default gateway is a gateway for the default route (`0.0.0.0/0`) in a device. In any case, you are now asking other questions that shoul be posted a new, different questions. Remember that SE sites are explicitly _not_ discussion forums. We have [chat] for that.

Answer (score 5):

It should also be noted, the all-zeros and all-ones addresses of a subnet are the network and broadcast addresses, respectively. Both are *reserved* and cannot be assigned to a host. In your example 10.0.0.0/24 and 10.0.0.255/24 are reserved addresses. (10.0.0.255/8 is just another host.)